# Getting real width of UITableViewCell's contentView before it displays

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a grouped table view with custom cells (created programmatically by subclassing, not with IB). To properly position custom cell's subviews (such as labels and text fields), I need to know the current width of the cell's `contentView` just before the cell displays (taking into account that real cell width in a table view can change (according to screen orientation, modal presentation style, etc.)).

if I override in custom cell class the `layoutSubviews` method, it works perfectly, but it can be called frequently, thus I have to reposition my subviews every time when it's called, even when there's no need to do that.

Please, recommend me more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way of doing this is by setting the `autoresizingMask` of the table cell. If you need to have more control over the layout, you can store the last used view width in a member variable, and only layout the subviews if this differs from the current view width.